# How to specify border attribute to a knob object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-knob

I have this code snippet for extending my knob properties...

```
                thickness : this.$.data('thickness') || 0.29,
                width : this.$.data('width') || 70,
                height : this.$.data('height') || 70,
```

how to include border property say , border= 1px solid #000; .... here

Comment: There's potential for a great "extend your knob properties" joke here

Comment: I've been trying for years!